# Application Force close while showing Map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I am using a demo for map view activity. There are no errors shown but when I run an application the map is not shown and application gets force closed.

Comment: Is your map key correct? i guess that will be the problem

Comment: yes..i checked it..its as i generated for my pc

Comment: Please provide your code and error log too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think..you have problem with emulator..
try this..

open avd manager..
make new avd with ..google api..and add properties